# Is there any other shorter method to to pass values at compile time in java other then using Scanner class and Command line?

Tags: java, command-line, java.util.scanner

i was exploring the ways in which one can pass values in java at compile time.So it striked my mind that,is there any other method to pass values in during compile time of a java program otherthen using Scanner class and Command Line.

Comment: i m asking for competitive programming purpose as using Scanner class is a tedious job when solving problems in competitive programming.

Comment: Please don't try to clarify your question by commenting on it.  Instead [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You could pass value through the args of you main.

Comment: Could you explain more exactly what you mean by "pass values at compile time"?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know:

## No, not really.

Java has this "helpful" feature that when you compile, no other input is accecpted unless it's console inputs (Command line arguments) or java.util.scanner **OR**  equivalent. There really isn't any other way to give the code something to work with.

However, there is also `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but that uses time as an input, so if there is a way to adapt your code around using constantly-updating times in milliseconds, i'll count that as another way to pass values into java.

Other that that, no.

Comment: What are you talking about? The Java compiler's input is a Java source code file. There are some command line options like `-cp` to set the classpath to control the compiler but this is no input to the Java program. Command line arguments, reading data with scanner or calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` is at runtime not compile time.